# Can we use FILESTREAM in case of SQL Server cluster

Tags: sql-server-2012, filestream

I saw this point on Technet article about RBS.

> The local FILESTREAM provider is supported only when it is used on
>   local hard disk drives or an attached Internet Small Computer System
>   Interface (iSCSI) device. You cannot use the local RBS FILESTREAM
>   provider on remote storage devices such as network attached storage
>   (NAS).

Does it mean we cannot use FILESTREAM in case of SQL Failover Cluster because Failover Cluster only works on NAS? But the thing is NAS is made available locally when setting Failover Cluster so may be FILESTREAM will work but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work most likely. Depending on the Failover cluster type, the underlying partition (ReFS / NTFS) and also the Storage System.

According to Technet article [Install SQL Server with SMB Fileshare as a Storage Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh759341.aspx) SMB 3 is not supported. You can have a look at the requirements in [Use Cluster Shared Volumes in a Failover Cluster](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612868.aspx). However, it seems to work with Microsoft SMB 3 (even though it is specified that it does not work).

If you use VmWare there is extensive documentation on that side in book [Virtualizing SQL Server with VMware: Doing IT Right](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321927753).

Comment: If it will not work then why Microsoft has written an article about it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645886.aspx

Comment: Windows share it is said that it is working, windows share uses SMB which is marked as not working with SQL server Clustering file streaming https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh759341.aspx which means that it works only if the Share is a Windows share and accessed afterwards by the other members of the cluster. There is no clear statement for that as far as I can tell

Comment: The fact that there is documentation on that and how to enable it for remote clients it means that it works in that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We have a scenario where .Net application is not able to access FileStream using the .Net SqlFileStream API. MSFT confirmed that the API is not supported when the FileStream is in CSV. We have to go non-CSV volume for FileStream contents.